# Using Stomp.js to implement chats with React Native. Subscribe and publish do not work

Tags: react-native, chat

When I talked to the backend, I said I set all the API paths correctly, but for some reason, the `console.log` inside the **subscription** function is not output and even if the chat is published, the contents are not in the DB.

What's wrong with the code?

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Client} from '@stomp/stompjs';
import SockJS from 'sockjs-client';
import styled from 'styled-components/native';
import SendIconGray from '../../assets/icon/chat-icon/ico_send_gray.svg';
import SendIconBlue from '../../assets/icon/chat-icon/ico_send_blue.svg';
import {API_URL} from '~/config';
import {useRoute} from '@react-navigation/native';

const username = (Math.random() * 1000000).toString().split('.')[0];

const TextEncodingPolyfill = require('text-encoding');

Object.assign('global', {
  TextEncoder: TextEncodingPolyfill.TextEncoder,
  TextDecoder: TextEncodingPolyfill.TextDecoder,
});

type Message = {
  roomHash: string;
  nickname: string;
  message: string;
  // file?: File; // file will be added later
};

type ChatroomProps = {
  roomHash: string;
  thumbnailPath: string;
  nickname: string;
};

const Chatroom = () => {
  const route = useRoute();
  const {roomHash, thumbnailPath, nickname} = route.params as ChatroomProps;
  const [client, changeClient] = useState<Client | null>(null);
  const [chatMessages, setChatMessages] = useState<Message[]>([]);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

  const connect = async () => {
    try {
      const clientData = new Client({
        webSocketFactory: () =>
          new SockJS(`${API_URL}/stomp/chat`),
        debug: (str) => {
          // console.log(str);
        },
        reconnectDelay: 5000,
        heartbeatIncoming: 4000,
        heartbeatOutgoing: 4000,
        onConnect: () => {
          subscribe();
        },
        onStompError: frame => {
          console.error(frame);
        },
      });



      clientData.activate();
      changeClient(clientData);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  const subscribe = () => {
   if (client) client.subscribe(
      `${API_URL}/exchange/chat.exchange/room.${roomHash}`,
      message => {
        if (message.body) {
          console.log(JSON.parse(message.body));
          setChatMessages(prev => [...prev, JSON.parse(message.body)]);
        } else {
          console.log('Failed');
        }
      },
    );
  };

  const publish = (message: string) => {
    if (client && !client.connected) return;
    if (message === '') return;

    if (client)
      client.publish({
        destination: `${API_URL}/chat.message.${roomHash}`,
        body: JSON.stringify({
          roomHash,
          message,
          nickname: username,
          // file // will be added later (should be sent as FormData)
        }),
      });

    setMessage('');
  };

  const disconnect = () => {
    if (client === null) return;

    client.deactivate();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    connect(); // only works

    return () => disconnect();
  }, []);

  return (
    <ChatroomBox>
      {chatMessages.length > 0 && (
        <ChatroomMessageBox>
          {chatMessages.length > 0 &&
            chatMessages.map(({nickname, message}, index) =>
              /** me */
              nickname === username ? (
                <ChatMessageRightBox key={index}>
                  <ChatMessageTextBox>
                    <ChatMessageText>{message}</ChatMessageText>
                  </ChatMessageTextBox>
                </ChatMessageRightBox>
              ) : (
                /** others */
                <ChatMessageLeftBox key={index}>
                  <ChatMessageTextBox>
                    <StackBox>
                      <ChatMessageGuestId>{nickname}</ChatMessageGuestId>
                      <ChatMessageText>{message}</ChatMessageText>
                    </StackBox>
                  </ChatMessageTextBox>
                </ChatMessageLeftBox>
              ),
            )}
        </ChatroomMessageBox>
      )}

      <ChatMessageSendBox>
        <ChatMessageSendBoxInput
          placeholder="채팅을 입력하세요"
          value={message}
          onChangeText={setMessage}
          onSubmitEditing={() => publish(message)}
          onBlur={() => publish(message)}
        />

        <SendIconBox onPress={() => publish(message)}>
          {message.length > 0 ? <SendIconBlue /> : <SendIconGray />}
        </SendIconBox>
      </ChatMessageSendBox>
    </ChatroomBox>
  );
};

export default Chatroom;
```

I want subscription and publication function to work.